# find out height of a UILabel which is size to fit

Tags: ios, uilabel

I am trying to find out the height of the UILabel when the height of the UILabel changes dynamically that is when it is `sizeToFit` enabled. What is the way to figure out the height of the UILabel? Of course the value `frame.size.height` is obviously wrong when I enable `sizeToFit`.

Thanks.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20996866/1280373

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this it may be help you..

```
-(CGSize)lblSize:(NSString *)content lblFont:(UIFont *)contectLblFont width:(int)Width
{
    CGSize maximumLabelSize;
    maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(Width,9999);
    NSAttributedString *attributedText =
    [[NSAttributedString alloc]
     initWithString:content
     attributes:@
     {
     NSFontAttributeName:contectLblFont
     }];
    CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){maximumLabelSize.width, CGFLOAT_MAX}
                                               options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               context:nil];
    CGSize size = rect.size;
    return size;
}
```

and use inside table view delegate

```
CGSize expectedLabelSize=[self lblSize:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[loadMoreArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"text"]] lblFont:cell.self.lbldetail.font width:310];

    cell.self.lbldetail.frame=CGRectMake(5,cell.imgProfile.frame.size.height+cell.imgProfile.frame.origin.y+2, 300,expectedLabelSize.height+10);
```

Answer (score 1):

I also using sizeToFit but getting Correct result try this may be helpfull. Plz try must.

```
 UILabel *detailsLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,50,320,30)];
 detailsLabel.text = [textDic valueForKey:@"Text"];
 detailsLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
 detailsLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
 [detailsLabel sizeToFit];
 [scrollViewObj addSubview:detailsLabel];
 NSLog(@"Label Height %f",  detailsLabel.frame.size.height );
```

Every thing working fine in my current project .Thanks Cheers ..

Comment: please try for a long text may be a 3 liner text. Thanks

Comment: Hello bro, I am using too much long text because my app is blog based app. but everything working is fine..

Comment: Plz try my code ... may be help full .. because It's working here totally fine ..

Comment: when are you calculating the height ?, i am doing it in a UITableViewCell inside a init method

Comment: Oh but I'm using this on scrollView  :(

Comment: amazing, @nitin-gohel, his link helped me, stackoverflow.com/a/20996866/1280373